# How delete an item from Service bus Queue?

Tags: c#, azure

I have the next code

```
public async Task Run(
            [ServiceBusTrigger("links",
            Connection = "serviceBus")]
            string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
    {
        if (myQueueItem == "test")
        {
            //if an item of string type is equal to test, just remove this item from Q.
            log.LogInformation("inside if");
        }
        // if successfull pass if just keep going
        log.LogInformation("outside");

        log.LogInformation($"Received message from bus: {myQueueItem}");

    }
```

How inside if block i can remove item from Q?

Comment: If all that code runs and doesn't end in an exception the item is removed. See the autocomplete attribute: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=python-v2%2Cin-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp#attributes if you need more control.

Comment: PeekLock behavior: The Functions runtime receives a message in PeekLock mode. It calls Complete on the message if the function finishes successfully, or calls Abandon if the function fails. If the function runs longer than the PeekLock timeout, the lock is automatically renewed as long as the function is running. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=python-v2%2Cin-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp#peeklock-behavior

Comment: able to delete the particular myQueueItem == "test" but adding null messages.

Answer (score 0):

Using LockToken I deleted the particular message.

Reference :

> I have referred this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=python-v2,in-process,extensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp#attributes) ,[MSDOC1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=python-v2,in-process,extensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp#attributes)  and   git [@gmantri](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/issues/84)

- Create a Azure Service Bus, Azure Service Bus Queue and send the message.

[image]

```cs
            string itemToRemove = "HelloUser";  // Replace with the specific item you want to remove
            QueueClient queueClient = new QueueClient(connectionString, queueName);
            MessageReceiver messageReceiver = new MessageReceiver(connectionString, queueName, ReceiveMode.PeekLock);
            while (true)
            {
                Message message = await messageReceiver.ReceiveAsync();
                  if (message == null || message.Body == null || message.Body.Length == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
              string messageContent = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body);  
          if((messageContent.Contains(itemToRemove)))
                {
                  await messageReceiver.AbandonAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
               
    log.LogInformation($"Item {itemToRemove}' not found in message with ID '{message.MessageId}' ");         
                }
            }

            await queueClient.CloseAsync();
            await messageReceiver.CloseAsync();
```

**Output**  :

[image]

- For checking messages in the queue.

[image]

[image]

**Output** :

[image]